# Azure Authentication changes user sid when adding scopes

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication, easy-auth

I have a Xamarin app that uses Azure AppService for auth.

I did not use email scope for auth before, but now I have added it. Interestingly, once the email scope is added and user authenticates, the provider requests new consent with the new scope. BUT the user gets another sid.

I got 100% repro at least with the email scope for FaceBook and Microsoft providers.

I have one AppService with Facebook setup with email scope and another copy of AppService without email scope. Both AppServices give me consistent sids for my user if I auth, but they never match.

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug. I believe it's more of a limitation that Identity provider A doesn't know anything about Identity provider B. Each new identity provider you add to your AppService will generate a different ID.

Here's another [stack overflow Q related to Azure B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68132369/b2c-users-with-multiple-identities). Behind the scenes B2C and the Azure AppService Auth are doing the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not about different providers. It is about the same provider. The only difference is that an email scope got added.